# How will we handle Deep learning models when we have a low amount of data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cnn

How will we handle  Deep learning models when we have a low amount  of data either image data or text.
I am not very familiar with these things.
what steps to take when we train the deep learning models with low amount data.

Comment: I mostly work on computer vision (CNN), but the most common things we do is to use **pretrained models** and fine tune them (transfer learning), which saves a lot of data. but another common practise is to use **data augmentation** (creating new images from the dataset).

Comment: Why use deep learning?

Comment: Hi Dave, if there is any need use Deep learning for that I asked this question